# Why does London equation not hold for normal conductors?

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity, conductors

In exercise 13.2 from *Fetter, Walecka - Quantum Theory of Many-Particles Systems* it is asked to obtain London equation as the Euler-Lagrange equation for the Helmholtz free energy and to discuss its validity. Free energy for arbitrary field $\vec{B}$ is:
$$F_s(T,B) = F_s(T,0) + \int d^3x \left[ \frac{1}{8\pi} B^2 + \frac{1}{2}n_smv^2\right]$$
Where $B$ is the magnetic field, $n_s$ is the density of superconducting charge carriers and $m$ is their mass.

Expressing $\vec{v}$ with respect to $\vec{B}$ ( $\frac{4\pi}{c} \vec{j} = \operatorname{curl} \vec{B} $)  and imposing $$ \frac{\delta}{\delta B_i}F_s(T,B) =0 $$ one straightforwardly obtains "London" equation
 $$\nabla^2 \vec{B} = \frac{1}{\lambda^2}\vec{B}.$$

**The problem is**: why should this not hold for a normal conductor?

Answer (score 1):

It actually does - sort of.

Remember that the free energy functional is a functional of two fields, the superconducting wavefunction $\psi$ and the magnetic field $\mathbf B$ (or the vector potential $\mathbf A$, if you prefer).  The equilibrium state is achieved when the functional is minimized with respect to both $\psi$ *and* $\mathbf B$.

As a result, you end up with two coupled differential equations which must be solved together.  You've written one of them, a differential equation for $\mathbf B$, but in the process you have made certain assumptions about $\psi$ (or really, $|\psi|^2$) which may not be consistent with the solution to the other.

I would suggest that you consider a superconducting metal and then imagine what about the above equations (and their solutions) changes as $T$ increases past $T_c$.  In particular, don't neglect what happens to $F_s(T,0)$, and what influence that has on $\psi$.

---

More explicitly, variation of $F_s$ with respect to $\psi$ or $n_s$ yields $|\psi|^2=n_s=0$ for $T>T_c$.  This being the case, the problem reduces to the minimization of

$$\int d^3x \frac{B^2}{8\pi}$$

subject to any prescribed boundary conditions.  However, setting the functional derivative to zero does not produce a differential equation (it simply demands that $\mathbf B=0$), reflecting the fact that the inclusion of boundary conditions generically requires a differential equation to accommodate them.  As it stands, prescribing $\mathbf B$ on the boundary and that $\frac{\delta F_s}{\delta \mathbf B}\sim \mathbf B = 0$ on leaves the system overdetermined and inconsistent.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to think about it. Anyway, for a bulk normal conductor, $ \psi $ is identically zero so i don't get how a coupling with the $ \psi $ equation could rise.

Comment: @Edison Yes, that's precisely what I meant.  Above $T_c$, the equation for $\psi$ dictates that it vanishes everywhere, but that means something non-trivial for the last term in your integral.

Comment: I don't get it. Are you saying that $\psi = 0$ implies $\mathbf{v} = 0$ so the Euler Lagrange equation becomes $ \mathbf{B} = 0$? However, I think that the comparison with Ginzburg Landau theory could be misleading. This should be a classical analogue of GL in fact we use $\mathbf{v}$ for kinetic term instead of the gauge invariant quantum mechanical momentum $-i\hbar \mathbf{\nabla} + \frac{e}{c} \mathbf{A}$

Comment: It implies that $|\psi|^2=n_s=0$, but yes, that is the outcome.  If you don't want to talk about $\psi$, you can vary with respect to $n_s$ - you just need to take into account the non-holonomic constraint $n_s \geq 0$.  Either way, the result is the same: in the absence of superelectrons to produce the kinetic term, you are asking for the $\mathbf B$ field which minimizes $\int d^3x B^2/8\pi$ subject to any prescribed boundary conditions.

Comment: @Edison I've updated my answer to include more.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the $\frac{1}{2}n_s m v^2$ term. In superconductors, the kinetic energy can form a significant fraction of an electron's (or, really, a Cooper pair's) energy, while in ordinary conductors the contribution of the kinetic energy is negligible. This is because in a superconductor the pairs move together in a rigid, coherent state over the entire macroscopic volume of the sample, while in a normal metal the electrons' wave functions are incoherent beyond a very short microscopic length scale.